"PageRotate" and "PageRotate90" shows in pdf by using pdflscape package
In pdflatex, I've used the package pdflscape to rotate a figure at a certain page in my document.
\usepackage{pdflscape}
...
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

However, in my generated pdf, there is two empty pages with "PageRotate" and "PageRotate90", see figure below:
How can I suppress or delete both pages?

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

We don't need your actual code so long as the MWE can reproduce the error.
